# Countable product of finite sets with a new metric, compact?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness, products

Suppose we have a finite set $E$. Is it true that $E^n$ is compact?
The metric on $E^n$ is :
$$d(\omega,\omega\prime)=\begin{cases}2^{-\inf \{ n \in \mathbf N:\omega _n \ne \omega'_n\} }&{\omega \ne \omega '}\\ 0&{\omega = \omega '} \end{cases}$$

My idea is as below:

For an arbitrary sequence, projection on the first element will give a one dimensional
sequence which has a repetitive subsequence. Considering this subsequence in the main infinite dimensional sequence one can continue this process to find for each $n$, a subsequence which has fixed $n$ elements in its first $n$ places. Unfortunately I cannot convince myself this solution can be extended for the infinite case(the whole sequence). Can someone give me a reason why this is correct for the whole sequence or do I need something else rather than this reasoning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $d(\omega,\omega')<2^{-n}$ iff $\omega_k=\omega_k'$ for all $k\le n$. It follows immediately that the topology generated by $d$ is the product topology on $E^{\Bbb N}$, considered as a product of discrete $|E|$-point spaces. As such it is compact by the Tikhonov's product theorem.

Your argument is doing it the hard way, but it does work. Suppose that $\sigma=\langle\omega^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $E^{\Bbb N}$, where $\omega^n=\langle\omega_k^n:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$. As you say, there is an $e_0\in E$ such that $$A_0=\{n\in\Bbb N:\omega_0^n=e_0\}$$ is infinite. Suppose that for some $m>0$ we have already chosen $e_k\in E$ and infinite sets $A_k\subseteq\Bbb N$ for each $k<m$ in such a way that $A_{k+1}\subseteq A_k$ for $k=0,\dots,m-1$, and $\omega_k^n=e_k$ for all $n\in A_k$. Then there is an $e_m\in E$ such that $$A_m=\{n\in A_{m-1}:\omega_m^k=e_m\}$$ is infinite, and the recursive construction goes through to yield a sequence $\omega=\langle e_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in E^{\Bbb N}$. It’s straightforward to check that $\omega$ is a cluster point of $\sigma$.

(By the way, this argument is essentially that used to prove [König’s lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma), of which this is an immediate consequence.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would not consider my way the hard way because Tychonoff's problem has such hard proof, and using that for this looks like to kill a fly with bazooka!

But one thing I don't understand about your proof is what you mean by recursive construction are you referring to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction#Transfinite_recursion

Comment: @Naji: (The Tikhonov theorem is actually pretty easy to prove if you learn about convergence in terms of filters.) A recursive construction/definition is one that proceeds in stages, at each stage constructing/defining something in terms of things that have already been defined. For example, a recursive construction/definition of the factorial function is given by $n!=n(n-1)!$ for $n>0$, and $0!=1$. Here I constructed $\omega$ recursively, one term at a time, and the definition at each stage depended on what I’d already done at earlier stages.

Comment: @Naji: I prefer the more accurate transliteration *Tikhonov* of the Cyrillic *Тихонов*.

Comment: Well I am afraid that wouldn't work! That recursive method you are referring to is for finite stages and would not help for infinite case. For any $n$ you can prove the existence of your sequence but for infinity(whole sequence) you need something like limit I believe. I read these things many years ago and I cannot recall correctly.

I didn't know it has such a spelling. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Naji: It most certainly does work; it’s a bog-standard basic technique, though you’ll have to take a serious set theory course if you want to see a formal justification.

Comment: I did actually took serious courses in set theory, but as I told I forgot the things. 

OK. Let me put it in the way I remember. $\omega$ is the first infinite ordinal(not the $\omega$ here!). My problem was with the existence of the limit as a sequence. To prove that such a limit exist, we are using the fact that for each ordinal $\ beta<\omega $ such a sub sequence exists. Therefore using Transfinite recursion the same holds for ordinal number $\omega$. This completes the proof of existence.

Comment: @Naji: You need only finite recursion here: you need only show that for each $n$ a suitable element $e_n$ exists. You’d need transfinite recursion only if you wanted to extend the sequence to length $\omega+1$.

Comment: by going from $n$ to $n+1$ you will never get $\omega$. And actually for for $\omega +1$ you don't need the transfinite induction theorem in limit case but in successor case but in the case I mentioned you need it in limit case:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction#Transfinite_induction

Comment: @Naji: No, you don’t. You need only all of the finite cases. The limit case would be defining $e_\omega$, which you never do. (This is my field, and I do know what I’m talking about.)

Comment: Exactly, and I was asking about the existence of the limit sub-sequence which is a sequence here and the limit itself.(Then excuse my misconceive, and if you think it can help please provide a reference that I could understand it as the way you say so.)

Comment: @Naji: I’m not constructing a subsequence of the sequence $\sigma$; it’s not necessary. I’m constructing the sequence $\omega$, which requires only ordinary recursion, and pointing out that it is a cluster point of the sequence $\sigma$. Since $E^{\Bbb N}$ is a metric space, it is then trivial that there is a subsequence of $\sigma$ that converges to $\omega$.

Comment: Yeah same thing, The existence of that infinite vector which is the limit itself is a matter of question for me. I will mark your answer as correct but still I would be happy if you guide me with a reference with a subsection of it that I could read and comprehend it. 

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Naji: But $\omega$ is not a limit of anything. The recursion shows that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we can construct a suitable $e_n\in E$, and the (ordinary) recursion theorem then says that we can collect the ordered pairs $\langle n,e_n\rangle$ to form the sequence $\omega$. This is in principle exactly the same thing that we do in defining the factorial function recursively. There’s a semi-formal discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition).

Comment: @Naji: You’re welcome!